# Postgres: After importing production database (with replication) to my local machine, I notice network packets being sent and received from macbook

Tags: macos, postgresql

I've been a MySQL guy, and now I'm working with Postgres so I am learning. Wondering if someone can tell me why my postgres process on my macbook is sending and receiving data over my network. I am just noticing this is happening for the first time - so maybe it's been going on before this and I just never noticed postgres does this.

What has me a bit nervous, is that I pulled down a production datadump from our server which is set up with replication and I imported it to my local postgres db. The settings in my postgresql.conf don't indicate replication is turned on. So it shouldn't be streaming out to anything, right?

If someone has some insight into what may be happening, or why postgres is sending/receiving packets, I'd love to hear the easy answer (and the complex one if there's more to what's happening).

This is a postgres install via Homebrew on MacOSX.

Thanks in advance!

Some final thoughts: It's entirely possible, I guess, that Mac's activity monitor also shows local 'network' traffic stats. Maybe this isn't going out to the internets.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I would **not** expect `replication` to be enabled for a DB that was dumped from a server that had it if the server to which it was restored had no `replication` configured at all.

More detail:

Normally, to get a local copy of a database in `Postgres`, one would do a `pg_dump` of the remote database (this could be done from your laptop, pointing at your server), followed by a `createdb` on your laptop to create the database stub and then a `pg_restore` pointed at the dump to populate its contents. [**Edit:** Re-reading your post, it seems like you may perhaps have done this, but meant that the dump you used had replication enabled.)]

That would be entirely local (assuming no connections into the DB from off-box), so long as you didn't explicitly setup any replication or anything else that would go off-box. Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by importing **with replication**?

Also, if you're concerned about remote traffic coming from `Postgres`, try running this command a few times over the period of a minute or two (when you are seeing the traffic):

```
netstat | grep postgres
```

In general, `replication` in Postgres in configured at a server level, and has to do with things such as the master server shipping `WAL` files to the standby server (for `streaming replication`). You would have almost certainly have had to setup entries in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` to ensure that the `standby server` had access (such as a `replication` entry in the latter conf file). Assuming you didn't do steps such as this, I think it can pretty safely be concluded that there's no replication going on (especially in conjunction with double-checking via `netstat`).

You might also double-check the `Postgres log` to see if it's doing anything replication related. In a default install, that'd probably be in /var/log/postgresql (although I'm not 100% sure if `Homebrew` installs put it somewhere else).

Comment: Thanks Ken. To clarify 'importing with replication' - I copied down a backup .sql file that gets saved up to S3 every half hour and I ran something similar to 'psql my_dev_db < the_name_of_the_backup.sql'. So what I meant was, the .sql file had roles in it for replication and other things of a replication-y nature.  My conf files are commented out where replication is set up - so this is just a standard install. I'm accepting your very satisfying answer - which alleviates a slight bit of 'not sure what's happening' paranoia. I'll check on that traffic to see if it's really outbound. doubt it.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Your use of `psql` to restore the db should be functionally equivalent (at a basic level) to my method of `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll read up a bit more on those methods of importing. I might be bugging you more in the future on this Postgres stuff...until then, thanks again for chiming in on this.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just make sure to create a new question. =)

Answer (score 0):

If it's UDP traffic, to and from a high port, it's likely to be [PostgreSQL's internal statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6BCB9D8A16AC4241919521715F4D8BCEA0F902@algol.sollentuna.se).

These are [pre-bound to prevent interference](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/19082.1273003752@sss.pgh.pa.us) and should not be accessible outside of PostgreSQL.