# Why is Postgres sending data somewhere?

Tags: postgresql, networking, postgresql-9.3

I installed PostgreSql 9.3.4 on my Mac Book using the graphical installer from EnterpriseDB.

I’m just using PostgreSql for development and I’m only using it from localhost, however, I found that one of postgres processes is keep using network. the sent and rcvd packets in the activity monitor are keep growing even while I'm not connecting postgres from my application or pgAdmin.

What is this? 
Where is the data being sent?

Comment: Is there any chance it's the loopback interface? PostgreSQL uses UDP for the statistics collector.

Comment: Sounds like some similarities to a question I answered a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837216/postgres-after-importing-production-database-with-replication-to-my-local-mac/23839799#23839799. You might want to try some of the things I mention in that question.

Comment: Thanks, guys.
I tried the Ken's way in the link and I found this is not remote traffic. Mac’s activity monitor seems to show local network traffic. Just to make sure I disconnected my laptop from the network, and the sent/rcvd packets kept growing. 
I also sampled the process in mac’s activity monitor, and I see PgstatCollectorMain in the call graph. I don’t know what exactly this is, but from the name, this should be the statistics collector as Craing says.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Since it seems like it was similar, it seems best to not duplicate my answer here and have you accept it. Instead, could you upvote my answer in the question I linked, since it appears to have resolved your issue?

Comment: Ken, it looks like I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer at the moment. :(

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, if you reach the necessary threshold (I think it may be 50), please upvote it then. =)